# Join table attribute updates in Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a many-to-many relation setup for a data model which deals with a problem domain of Members and Addresses.  Basically a 'member' can have multiple 'addresses', think of like when you have a work address and a home address.

I want to store additional attributes on the join table and save data, apart from the foreign key attributes.  There are many examples on the net about many-to-many relations, but I've not found details/examples on storing the extra data.

Here is the problem that i'm stuck with.

The models are setup as:

**Models**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :member_addresses
   has_many :addresses, :through => :member_addresses
end

class MemberAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :address   # foreign key for address -> address_id
   belongs_to :member    # foreign key for member ->member_id
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :member_addresses
   has_many :members, :through => :member_addresses

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The 'accepts_nested_attributes' on the Address class is for the nested-forms.

**Database Schema/Migrations**
The tables (simplified for posting) are defined as

```
create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "firstline"
    t.string  "state"
    ....
end

create_table "member", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    ....
end

create_table "member_addresses", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer "member_id"
   t.integer "address_id"
   t.string  "address_type"
end
```

The field 'address_type' on the join table is intended for flagging the type of the address that is associated with the member (aka; "home" or "work")

***It is updating this field that is where I'm getting stuck.***

**Controllers & View**

The member_controller setups the model like:

```
members_controller.rb
def new
   @member = Member.new
   @member.addresses.build    #pre-build the associated address
end
```

Then the view for the member page **new** action is

<%= form_for @member do |m| %>

```
  <%= m.label :first_name, "First Name"%>
  <%= m.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>

  <%= m.fields_for :addresses do |addrform|%>
    <%= addrform.label :firstline %>
    <%= addrform.text_field :firstline %>
  <% end %>

  <br />
  <%= label_tag 'Type of address' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'addrtype'    %>
  <br />
  <%= m.submit "Add" %><br />
```

<% end %>

The idea is that with the 'accepts_nested_attributes' on the **Member** model I can enter the data on the form to add in the name and address attributes.  The additional **label_tag** is for the data to be posted for the address type that I want to store

So when the form is filled in the post data (form a trap) looks like:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
     "authenticity_token"=>"E0R038rcdJmBGjjxQ9nQLHGVbzM4ejA0vsEaIvqkwkE=",
     "member"=>{"first_name"=>"James",
     "last_name"=>"SMith",
     "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"firstline"=>"this is the first line"}}},
     "addrtype"=>"home",
     "commit"=>"Add"}
```

All good - i'm getting my **Member** data and the **Address** data, as well as the additional field 'addrtype' which is to be used for carrying my additional data

Now how to get the data into the relation or join table ?  On the **member_controller create action**

```
def create
   # create a member with the params posted 
   @member = Member.new(params[:member])

   # get data for 'relation data'
   @addr_type = params[:addrtype]



  if @member.save!
      #update the relation now created with the address type
      @member.member_addresses.first.address_type = @addr_type

      # save the relationship (is this necessary?)
      @member.save!

      redirect_to members_path
  end
```

As you can see in the **create** I'm attempting to fill in the data on the join table and then force a save again so that the relation or association with the additional attribute is saved.

This doesn't work, and/or I'm doing it wrong.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your models to something like this:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :member_addresses
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :member_addresses, :allow_destroy => true
end

class MemberAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :member    
   has_many :addresses
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy => true
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :member_addresses
end
```

And change your member_controller.create method to

```
@member = Member.new(params[:member])
```

This should allow you to create MemberAddresses and Addresses via the MemberController.create method.

These 2 RailsCasts might also be worth a look

[#196 Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
[#197 Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

Not as fluent in Rails as I would like to be, however research suggests that possibly this might work:

Instead of

`@member.member_addresses.first.address_type = @addr_type`

Try

`@member.member_addresses.create(:address_type => @addr_type)`

Comment: Correct - it works provided that the @member is saved first otherwise you get ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved

Comment: The only problem is that given there is a @member.save!, necessary to have the parent saved, the additional 'create' results in two records created in the MemberAddresses join table;  one for the first save, which has the two foreign keys and one for 'create' which has the address_type field and the id of the member object.  It's missing the  address_id field